# Open specific slide in Bootstrap 4 modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, slick.js

I want to use a single Bootstrap 4 modal to show different content inside a slider.
At the moment I've 4 boxes which should open in a modal to show more information.
If the modal is open, I want to slide between the content of all the boxes.

At the moment I'm not sure how to adress a single slide inside the modal. I could open the modal but it will always shows all slides at once.

Is there any way to open the modal AND point to a single slide?

For example: Click on "Box 2" opens the modal and shows slide 2 in the slider.

**Here's my working code example:** https://codepen.io/cray_code/pen/oPxwYq

```js
$('.slider-modal').slick({
  dots: false,
  arrows: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
 });
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <a href="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
     <h1>Box 1</h1>
     <p>Should open Modal and <strong>slide 1</strong></p>
    </a>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <a href="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
     <h1>Box 2</h1>
     <p>Should open Modal and <strong>slide 2</strong></p>
    </a>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <a href="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
     <h1>Box 3</h1>
     <p>Should open Modal and <strong>slide 3</strong></p>
    </a>
   </div>

   <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <a href="#exampleModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
     <h1>Box 4</h1>
     <p>Should open Modal and <strong>slide 4</strong></p>
    </a>
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
 
 <!-- Modal -->
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
   <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
     </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

     <div class="slider-modal">
      <div>Slide 1</div>
      <div>Slide 2</div>
      <div>Slide 3</div>
      <div>Slide 4</div>
     </div>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with some other extra data attribute like this `data-innertarget`.Apply the event on modal show

**[`Codepen link`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OoNgoJ)**

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal',function(e){
     var elem = e.relatedTarget;
      $('.slider-modal').find('.slide').hide();
     $($(elem).attr('data-innertarget')).show()
})
```

Comment: thanks! it works to open the right slide. But if I scroll through the slides, it shows no content in the slide prev/next slide